# .sst files are daily increasing in cockroachdb on path /var/lib/cockroach/cockroach-data

Tags: cockroachdb

.sst files are daily increasing in cockroachdb on path /var/lib/cockroach/cockroach-data

daily there are lots of .sst files are getting created in my cockroachdb cluster at the host path /var/lib/cockroach/cockroach-data.

Can I delete them? its a critical environment and We can not just delete those files without knowing the impact.

however, they are piling up the disk utilization.

[root@winprd-vck001 cockroach-data]# ls -lrth | grep sst | wc -l
4616

-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach  8.9M May 10 21:27 5266230.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   50M May 10 21:35 5266274.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   17M May 10 22:00 5266420.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   12M May 10 22:00 5266421.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   17M May 10 22:11 5266468.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach  9.0M May 10 23:04 5266745.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   17M May 10 23:04 5266746.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   18M May 10 23:19 5266806.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   31M May 10 23:19 5266807.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   11M May 11 00:11 5267051.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   28M May 11 00:15 5267083.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   64M May 11 00:15 5267089.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   20M May 11 00:30 5267173.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach  1.2M May 11 00:30 5267174.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   64M May 11 01:01 5267295.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   64M May 11 01:01 5267296.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   64M May 11 01:01 5267297.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   14M May 11 01:01 5267298.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   17M May 11 01:20 5267403.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   18M May 11 01:20 5267404.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach  571K May 11 01:20 5267405.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach  9.6M May 11 01:57 5267591.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   17M May 11 01:57 5267592.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   12M May 11 01:57 5267593.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   65M May 11 01:58 5267646.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   19M May 11 01:58 5267647.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   65M May 11 01:58 5267674.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   13M May 11 01:58 5267680.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   64M May 11 02:33 5267929.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   19M May 11 02:33 5267930.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   27M May 11 03:44 5268110.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach  4.5M May 11 03:51 5268155.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   34M May 11 03:51 5268156.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach  2.6M May 11 04:14 5268235.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach  8.3M May 11 05:17 5268436.sst
-rw-r----- 1 cockroach cockroach   17M May 11 06:00 5268696.sst

Answer (score 2):

**Those .sst files [are your data](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/architecture/storage-layer.html), don't delete them.**

If your disk utilization is higher than you'd like, but in a relatively steady state after 10 days of uptime, try decreasing your `gc.ttlseconds` zone configuration so that deleted rows are garbage-collected more frequently. Any time that is comfortably longer than your slowest query is generally safe, although you'll want to make sure not to interfere with backups or change data capture jobs.

If your disk utilization is continuing to creep up over time, either

- **Your data is growing faster than you're deleting rows:** This is a good problem to have. You can solve it with money by adding more nodes, or by periodically deleting stale data (or archiving it in an external system). In CockroachDB 22.1 (in beta release as of May 11th 2022), you can automate the first part of this process by setting `ttl_expire_after` on a table in a [CREATE or ALTER statement](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/releases/v22.1#:%7E:text=A%20new%20row%20level%20TTL%20was%20added%20to%20CockroachDB%2C%20which%20is%20available%20as%20a%20beta%20feature.%20This%20allows%20users%20to%20use%20a%20special%20syntax%20to%20automatically%20mark%20rows%20for%20deletion.). Archiving can be done via [scheduled backups](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-schedule-for-backup.html) or [changefeeds](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-changefeed.html).
- **Something is preventing garbage collection:** Backups and changefeeds will protect old versions of rows from being garbage-collected until they've finished exporting them. If you have a long-running job that's not able to connect to its external sink, it could be preventing garbage collection indefinitely. This can be fixed by fixing the job. Other long-running jobs can prevent garbage collection of metadata if something's gone wrong.

Finally, if you're still in the first 10 days of a new cluster and you're seeing disk utilization slowly rise, that's expected. Your database is growing, and it's also accumulating time series statistical data for use in monitoring. No need to take action just yet.

Comment: cluster is running from last 2 years and I can see .sst files of February 2021 also, will they always keep on increasing?

Comment: You'll still see old files if the old rows haven't been deleted or updated. The overall disk utilization should only keep increasing if the amount of data in your database keeps increasing.